# Can I "update" ASP UpdateProgress when performing Asyc. Downloads?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have an ASP page which performs an Asyc. Download of a large zipped package of images.

I have been using the Ajax *updateprogress* control to keep the user from panicing, but this was when the page was pulling down a much smaller set of files.

My concern now is that the user will abort the process prematurely, and so **I would like to somehow provide some feedback to the user about the progress  of the downloads.**

Currently I have an event handler for *DownloadProgressChanged*, but I'm not sure how I should pass this information back to the client without introducing a bunch of messy javascript?

Comment: Im not sure I understand, wont the user see the file being downloaded in the browser dialog which for all the big browsers will show the % downloaded, please correct me of im wrong.

Comment: No - the download is happening first on the server-side based on metrics inputted by the user, which I then make available via a link that appears on the page after a post-back.

Comment: Never tried this myself, but what if you put an update panel and call update method in DownloadProgressChanged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by doing what mslliviu had suggested in the comments, using an updatePanel and calling the update method from DownLoadProgressChanged.